# When scrolling still see a hidden div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 separate divs. One is where I click a link and it opens up a sidebar (for navigation) and the other div is where basically all of my content goes.

```
<div class='sidebar'>           
    links etc       
</div>

<div id="site"><a class='button-open' style="float: left;"></a>         
    All site information
</div>

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This is where I think something's messing up. For `body` (which is strictly the sidebar) the background is set for a color of `#556677`

```
 body {
        display: flex;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #333;
        background: #556677;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

But for the site ( where all the content is) I have the background set for an image:

```
#site {
        flex: 1;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #333;
        background-image: url(../_images/bg.jpg);       
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transition: transform .3s;
    }
```

I think this is the problem;

```
html,
body { height: 100%; }
```

Here's a preview of what it looks like when I scroll down the page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5HxV.png

Here's the sidebar in full effect:
http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/3cf3bd7855f21f47b671dcbb01741cff.png

This is just my js to open the navigation:

```
 <script>
                    $('.button-open').on('click', function() {
                        $('#site').toggleClass('isOpen');
                    });
                </script>
```

You guys happen to know why it's doing this when I scroll down the page? Thanks!

Update:

footer:

```
<div id="footer">                               
    <div id="social">
        <ul class="social-links clearfix">                      
            <li class="instagram"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></li>               
            <li class="twitter"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></li>       
            <li class="skype"></i></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>                      
</div>
```

css:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed; 
    bottom:0%;
    margin-left:5px;
    border: thin solid #CCC;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width:151px;
}
```

Comment: are the icons part of sidebar?

Comment: can you show a fiddle?

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes http://jsfiddle.net/zgv132r4/ i also added this link in the OP. for some reason it isn't showing the error on jsfiddle like it is on the actual site. hmm

Comment: i think you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/zgv132r4/1/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes what exactly was changed?

Comment: i just placed the social icons div in sidebar @kris

Comment: Wait a sec... on the first piece of code you're using CSS in HTML...